# How to send events with AngularJs $emit properly

Tags: angularjs, events, emit

I want to send data from one controller to another at a certain point. I have looked at the docs and googled before for solutions before posting. But can`t seem to get it to work properly.

I know $emit is for sending events up the scope hierarchy and $braodcast is for telegraphing downwards.

```
var app = angular.module('App.Controllers', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('FordelaPaBetankandeCtrl', 
        ['$rootScope', '$scope', 
            function ($rootScope, $scope) {

            $scope.$on("delatYrkande", function (selectedValue) {

            });

        }])
        .controller('UtskottCtrl',
            ['$rootScope', '$scope'
                function ($rootScope, $scope) {

                }])
        .controller('TidlinjeCtrl',
            ['$rootScope', '$scope'
                function ($rootScope, $scope) {

                }])
        .controller('UserInfoCtrl', ['$scope',
            function ($scope){

            }])
        .controller('VisaSammantradesplanCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope',
            function ($rootscope, $scope) {

            }])
        .controller('HanteraGrunddokumentCtrl',
            ['$rootScope', '$scope',
                function ($rootScope, $scope) {

                    $scope.Emit = function (selectedValue) {

                        $scope.$emit("delatYrkande", selectedValue);
                    }

                }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to broadcast from $rootScope:

```
$scope.Emit = function (selectedValue) {
    ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶e̶m̶i̶t̶(̶"̶d̶e̶l̶a̶t̶Y̶r̶k̶a̶n̶d̶e̶"̶,̶ ̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶V̶a̶l̶u̶e̶)̶;̶
    $scope.$root.$broadcast("delatYrkande", selectedValue);
}
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Events Propagation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-events-propagation)
- [AngularJS scope API Reference - $root](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$root)
- [AngularJS scope API Reference - $broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast)

Comment: doesn´t  $broadcast only transmit downwards? The controller i am trying to reach is the firts one and the emitting controller is last. Tried it and unfortunately it doesnt work.

Comment: Broadcast from $rootScope down to all the child scopes.